# Tag Assisant Critical Issue

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers) to have multiple analytics on my page.
When I add

> `ga('create', 'UA-12345-6', 'auto', {'name': 'newTracker'});`

The Google Tag Assistant gives me a critical issue:

> *Error: Method 'create' has 1 additional parameter*

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tag templates for universal analytics - there is an option to change the name of the tracker (since it seems you are using Google Tag Manager). Or you could put the setting for the cookie domain inside the configuration object:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'cookieDomain': 'auto',
   'name': 'newTracker'
});
```

This does not explain where the error message comes from (the message says there is one more parameter to the function than is defined in the function declaration, which as far as I can tell is not true), but one of the alternatives might work for you.